# CodeIgniter Flexi Auth Demo is Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have just installed Flexi Auth Plugin on my Linux system by exactly following the [Installation Guide](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/user_guide/installation)

When I navigate to code `http://localhost/codeigniter/` It is displaying the fancy demo page. However, when I click on "Demo" Link from top menu, Its displaying page not found error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /auth_lite/demo was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Do I need to configure my `routes.php`? In the installation guide, It says only to edit the default controller like this `$route['default_controller'] = "auth_lite/index";`

By the way, I am very new to CodeIgniter. If any one encountered this problem, please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does sound like your .htaccess file is either not working or not set as it should.

The server is looking for the filepath /auth_lite/demo where it should be passing that string to `index.php`.

Here's one of the most common .htaccess files for CI. Try it and see:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# developing in a subfolder? (http://localhost/app/) change this to app/
RewriteBase / 

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|swf|wymeditor|galleries|ffeiliau)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Try it and see.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. I tried using this code which it was kept under codeigniter root folder

Comment: I have also used the `.htaccess` provided by flex-auth. That one also not worked

Comment: Please state on what server stack you're testing, and if any other routes work or not.

Comment: One thing I found that, when I append index.php in the URL its working.

Comment: This is working fine in Windows using XAMP. However there is some problem in Linux

Answer (score 0):

search source-files for 'flexi_cart',
especially in three *library.php files, 
there are some string-entries, that have to be
changed to your own directory.

Seems to work with that changes.